# Jemdoc installation

Tags: python, markup

This is a somewhat obscure question, although if any of you are familiar with the markup language [jemdoc](http://jemdoc.jaboc.net/using.html) you'll be able to help me.

Python is installed, although the

```
jemdoc jemdoc.index
```

command is not working: 'jemdoc command not found'

jemdoc.py is in usr/local/bin/

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Perform the following steps

```
sudo cp jemdoc.py /usr/bin/jemdoc
```

Then make it executable

```
sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/jemdoc
```

Now any of the given commands should work

Like

```
jemdoc jemdoc.index
```

will create a index.html file.

Comment: How do we do the same in windows?